# Trouble switching between Python versions

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I am having difficulty switching between Python versions as 3.5 is not where I expected it to be and I don't know how to use it. I know it's there, but I can't find it or access it. Please help me understand what is going on. I'm running Mac OSX 10.12.1

```
$ which -a python
/usr/bin/python
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
$ usr/bin/python3.5.2
no such file or directory: usr/bin/python3.5.2
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
$ ls -ls /usr/bin/python*
32 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66848 Sep 13 18:56 /usr/bin/python
 0 -rwxr-xr-x  5 root  wheel    925 Jul 30 19:36 /usr/bin/python-config
 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Oct  8 12:56 /usr/bin/python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Oct  8 12:56 /usr/bin/python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     75 Oct  8 12:56 /usr/bin/python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     82 Oct  8 12:56 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
32 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  66848 Sep 13 18:57 /usr/bin/pythonw
 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Oct  8 12:56 /usr/bin/pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
 8 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     76 Oct  8 12:56 /usr/bin/pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
```

The only way I know 3.5 is on my system is because I have been using it in Pycharm (which is where I found the /Library/Frameworks/../python3.5 path)

I reinstalled Python 3.5, but it did not change the location.

What I really want to do is use Python 3.5 as default in Terminal, but I'll also settle for being able to set up 3.5 with virtualenv. (Almost all my programs run in 3.5: This problem is new since I switched from terminal to iTerm and ZSH)

I can launch a virtual environment by specifying the path, but the issue is 1. why is 3.5 installed somewhere else, and 2. why can't I find it from the command line?

```
$ virtualenv -p /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter 
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Comment: Have you tried `python3`? That's the default alias.

Comment: Thank you. Python3 launches python3.5, but when I try `Python3 my_file.py` I get module errors because it's not reading packages that are definitely installed and which work when I run from Pycharm

Comment: Are they installed in a virtualenv? `python3` is the system Python 3 installation, but you need to run the one in the virtualenv. It sounds like you would benefit from reading some tutorials on how virtual environments work.

Comment: They're not in a virtualenv

Comment: in your .bashrc -- `hash -d python` followed by `hash -p <path-to-python3> python`